# Tasks seem to start automatically

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm porting a program that had a very long loading time which was not improved at all when I ported it, as the slowness was because of accessing a db-server (and not sub-optimal code).  I have moved the loading onto a separate thread with the `Tasks` library and now the UI doesn't freeze as it loads, but it did make me curious about something:

The `Task.Factory` object has a method `StartNew` which is supposed to create a new task, start it, and return a reference to it.  This makes sense, but it seems that the `Task` constructor does the exact same thing.

When I do the following:

```
Task catsFromDB = new Task(() => AddCategoriesFromDB(cts.Token), cts.Token);
catsFromDB.Start();
```

I get an error `InvalidOperationException` which I really don't understand.  It seems to believe that I've kicked it off already.  Which I haven't.

**[EDIT]**

The erorr is: "InvalidOperationException, Start may not be called on task that has completed"

**[EDIT]**

The error was some cancellation code I included.  I needed to reset the cancellation before trying to run it again.

Comment: Are you sure it actually started?

Comment: @Rewinder: yup. Since it "works just fine."

Comment: Oop, just got back to it from over the weekend.  I was wrong.  It does not work.

Comment: Please supply the full stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I feel stupid, but it will be instructive to let others learn from my 'green' (as in "new", "inexperienced") error:

I needed the operation in question to be cancellable and re-runnable, so I had implemented a "CancelLoad" operation which always got run before doing the actual load.  It turns out that I forgot to create a new Token after canceling and waiting.

Comment: I made the exact mistake. I wanted a to repeat a process if the user clicked a button twice (SignalR). So as part of my Initialization I first called cancel on the token source reference.

Thanks for the Heads Up. You saved me loads of hairpulling

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce that behaviour. The code below only starts the task when you call `Start`.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Console.WriteLine("Creating task...");
        Task task = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Task executing"),
                             cts.Token);
        Console.WriteLine("Sleeping...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Starting task...");
        task.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

My *guess* is that somehow you're creating multiple tasks and starting some of them twice, and some of them not at all. If you can show a similar short-but-complete program which demonstrates the problem, we should be able to help more.

Comment: Hmmm...it's a good thought, but a quick "Find in Entire Solution" shows `new Task` to occur only once.  I'll see if I can whip up another example.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is more UI related: I think you might have code within `AddCategoriesFromDB(cts.Token)` that tries to update the UI.  However, since you're now on a different thread than the UI is, your updates to the UI will throw errors.  Is this the case?

Comment: This is true.  It does update the UI, but I use "BeginInvoke"